# dynamically adding options to select2 in blade component with laravel livewire and alpinejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, jquery-select2, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

When I dynamically update the options inside of a select 2, the dropdown isn't getting updated. Based on [this](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/1878#issuecomment-714749199), I've tried emitting an event that I'm then listening for in my select2 component to handle adding the options. Unfortunately, it's not working either. What am I missing to get this working correctly?

```php
@props(['id', 'isDisabled' => null, 'usePlaceholder' => null, 'isDeferred' => false])
<div wire:ignore x-data="{
    model: @entangle($attributes->wire('model')),
}" x-init="select2 = $($refs.select)
    .not('.select2-hidden-accessible')
    .select2({
        placeholder: 'Select an option',
        minimumResultsForSearch: 10,
    });
select2.on('select2:select', (event) => {
    if (event.target.hasAttribute('multiple')) {
        model = Array.from(event.target.options).filter(option => option.selected).map(option => option.value);
    } else {
        model = event.params.data.id
    }
});
select2.on('select2:unselect', (event) => {
    model = Array.from(event.target.options).filter(option => option.selected).map(option => option.value);
});
$watch('model', (value) => {
    select2.val(value).trigger('change');

});" style="width:100%;" id="select2-{{ $id }}">
    <select x-ref="select" {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'form-select form-control select2']) }} id="{{ $id }}" data-width="100%" @if ($isDisabled) disabled @endif>
        @if ($usePlaceholder)
            <option></option>
        @endif
        {{ $slot }}
    </select>
</div>


@push('custom-scripts')
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#' + @js($id)).on('change', function(event) {
                let selectedValue = $('#' + @js($id)).select2('val');

                //emit an event that listeners can tap into when select2 value changes. This enables things like showing dependent dropdowns.
                Livewire.emit('select2Changed', {
                    id: @js($id),
                    value: selectedValue
                });
            });

            //  //using the livewire message.processed hook to set the value of the select2 component when a dropdown doesn't get loaded on initial page load, i.e. another livewire component with a select is mounted after page load. 
            //  //i.e. when it's not initialized until the user performs some action. If not for this, the dropdown would not have a starting value.
            Livewire.hook('message.processed', (message, component) => {
                let selectId = @js($id);
                let select2 = $('#' + @js($id));

                if (component.data[selectId] !== undefined && component.data[selectId] !== null && component.data[selectId] !== '') {
                    if (component.data[selectId] !== select2.find(':selected').val()) {
                        select2.val(component.data[selectId]).trigger('change');
                    }
                }
            });


            window.addEventListener('addItemsToDropdown', event => {
                console.log(event.detail.data) <--this shows my array of elements containing my newly added one.
                let select2 = $('#' + event.detail.selectId);
                let data = event.detail.data;

                data.forEach(function(item) {
                    let option = new Option(Object.values(item)[0], Object.values(item)[1], false, false);
                    select2.append(option);
                });

                select2.trigger('change');
            });
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

This is the event I'm dispatching:

```php
$this->dispatchBrowserEvent('addItemsToDropdown', ['selectId' => 'mySelectId', 'data' => $this->data]);
```